# How to display thumbnails like Explorer or Finder

Tags: firemonkey

I have written a Firemonkey app and it saves its files with extension ".qrmx".

In both Explorer (Windows) and Finder (Mac), its thumbnail looks like a blank sheet of paper with the top right corner curled over. This is, I think, the generic thumbnail. How can I introduce a thumbnail specific to my app?

Comment: You meant application icon or something else? For changing application icon, go to _Project > Options_ menu and find the _Application_ in left menu. 

Note: each platform requires different kind of images (resolutions, extensions and quantity) so be sure that your target platform and debug-release build configs are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally dawned on me that I needed to associate my program files with my program. For Windows, I was able to do this within the Inno Setup installer by defining Registry settings. For OS X, I was able to do it with settings in the info.plist file. Both operating systems then used the appropriate icons from my app.